# URL rewrite regex conversion

Tags: regex, wordpress, url-rewriting

I'm having trouble trying to learn how to write this URL into a regex template to add in as a rewrite. I've tried various regex sandboxes to figure it out on my own but they won't allow a '/' for instance when I copy an expression from here for testing: [image: demo]

I've got a custom post type (publications) with 2 taxonomies (magazine, issue) which I'm trying to create a good looking URL for.

After many hours I've come here to find out how I can convert this.

```
index.php?post_type=publications&magazine=test-mag&issue=2016-aug
```

To a templated regex expression (*publication*, *magazine* and *issue* are constant) that can output.

```
http://example.com/publications/test-mag/2016-aug/
```

Hopefully with room to extend if an article is followed through from that page.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:**

I've got this for my rule:

```
^publications/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$
```

and this for my match:

```
^index.php?post_type=publications&magazine=$matches[1]&issue=$matches[2]$
```

and testing with this:

```
http://localhost/publications/test-mag/2016-aug/
```

but its giving me a 404. What's the problem?

Comment: Which URL Rewrite engine will you be using?

Comment: @10100111001 Wordpress rewrite

Answer (score 1):

`^index\.php\?post_type=publications&magazine=([^&]+)&issue=([^&]+)$`

- `^` start of string
- `index\.php\?post_type=publications&magazine=` literal text
- `([^&]+)` one or more non-ampersand characters (will get all text up to the next url parameter. this is captured as a group
- `&issue=` literal text
- `([^&]+)` one or more non-ampersand characters. also captured
- `$` end of string

Comment: Thanks so much and do these **([^&]+)** act as a sort of variable for the match as well?

Comment: They don't. They just make it so that you get get those strings separately in your code.

Comment: And how can I call back those strings in the rewrite? Sorry, i'm completely new to regex

Comment: Looks like @1252748 has got that covered. I'm good at regex, but not too familiar with wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'index.php?post_type=publications&magazine=test-mag&issue=2016-aug';
preg_match('/magazine=([\w-]+?)&issue=([\w-]+)/', $str, $matches);
$res = 'http://example.com/' . $matches[1] . '/' . $matches[2] . '/';
echo $res;  // => http://example.com/test-mag/2016-aug/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`add_rewrite_rule`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) method in the WP Rewrite API to accomplish this.

```
add_rewrite_rule('^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$','index.php?post_type=publications&magazine=$matches[1]&issue=$matches[2]','top');
```